# Angular 2 Material. Same MdIcon that works in one component fails in the other

Tags: angular, svg, angular-material

I just upgraded from `ng2 rc4` with `material2 alpha6` to `ng2 rc5` with `material 2 alpha7-2`. A new error pops up on code that worked before when I use `<md-icon>`.

I cannot see the full error text because instead I get `Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function` error (the app crashes), with the top lines in the stacktrace being:

```
MdIconRegistry.prototype.getNamedSvgIcon
    @angular2-material/icon/icon-registry.js:180:16
MdIcon.prototype.ngOnChanges
    @angular2-material/icon/icon.js:107:17
```

If I `console.log()` the id of the icon sought just above `icon-registry.js @ line 180`, I see `ic_lightbulb_outline_24px`.  This icon is present in my svg sprite, but it displayed properly before I upgraded today to `material 2 alpha 7-2`.  Here is its section in the svg sprite:

```
...<svg viewBox="..." id="ic_lightbulb_outline_24px"><path d="..."/></svg>...
```

The template:

```
<md-icon svgIcon="ic_lightbulb_outline_24px"></md-icon>
```

In my main `AppComponent` I have

```
this._iconRegistry.addSvgIconSet('src/icons/sprite.defs.svg');
```

I've also imported `MdIconModule` into the main `AppModule`.  What's really puzzling is that

- the same icon from the same sprite file works on other components and
- this worked before the upgrade!

Two more pieces of info:

- this problem only affects lazy-loaded modules
- The same template component with `<md-icon>` will work fine if it's used on the template of a component loaded at app launch, but will fail with this error if it's used on the template of a component that was lazy-loaded

[I've built a Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eCWl2Gop6Yx1yOnjlUzl?p=preview) demonstrating the problem. You'll notice that the eagerly loaded components (`AppComponent` and `HomeComponent`) are able to display the icon. However, `LazyLoadedComponent` cannot.

Below is the full stacktrace:

```
MdIconRegistry.prototype.getNamedSvgIcon /@angular2-material/icon/icon-registry.js:180:16
MdIcon.prototype.ngOnChanges /@angular2-material/icon/icon.js:107:17
anonymous/_View_UserProfileComponent6.prototype.detectChangesInternal@UserProfileComponent.ngfactory.js:1318:29
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12586:13
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectContentChildrenChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12604:17
anonymous/_View_UserProfileComponent1.prototype.detectChangesInternal@UserProfileComponent.ngfactory.js:294:3
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12586:13
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectContentChildrenChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12604:17
anonymous/_View_UserProfileComponent0.prototype.detectChangesInternal@UserProfileComponent.ngfactory.js:37:3
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12586:13
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectViewChildrenChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12612:17
anonymous/_View_UserProfileComponent_Host0.prototype.detectChangesInternal@UserProfileComponent.ngfactory.js:28:3
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12586:13
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectContentChildrenChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12604:17
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChangesInternal /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12596:13
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12586:13
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectViewChildrenChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12612:17
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChangesInternal /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12597:13
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12586:13
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectContentChildrenChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12604:17
anonymous/_View_AppComponent0.prototype.detectChangesInternal@AppComponent.ngfactory.js:445:3
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12586:13
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectViewChildrenChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12612:17
anonymous/_View_AppComponent_Host0.prototype.detectChangesInternal@AppComponent.ngfactory.js:30:3
AppView</AppView.prototype.detectChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12586:13
ViewRef_</ViewRef_.prototype.detectChanges /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:10804:58
ApplicationRef_</ApplicationRef_.prototype.tick/< /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:10191:79
ApplicationRef_</ApplicationRef_.prototype.tick /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:10191:17
ApplicationRef_/<.next/< /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:10095:103
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke /zone.js/dist/zone.js:323:20
NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onInvoke /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9245:36
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke /zone.js/dist/zone.js:322:20
Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.run /zone.js/dist/zone.js:216:25
NgZoneImpl</NgZoneImpl.prototype.runInner /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9276:64
NgZone</NgZone.prototype.run /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9505:55
ApplicationRef_/<.next /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:10095:73
EventEmitter</EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn< /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9168:58
SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub /rxjs/Subscriber.js:225:13
SafeSubscriber.prototype.next /rxjs/Subscriber.js:174:17
Subscriber.prototype._next /rxjs/Subscriber.js:124:9
Subscriber.prototype.next /rxjs/Subscriber.js:88:13
Subject.prototype._finalNext /rxjs/Subject.js:128:13
Subject.prototype._next /rxjs/Subject.js:120:13
Subject.prototype.next /rxjs/Subject.js:77:9
EventEmitter</EventEmitter.prototype.emit /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9156:58
NgZone</NgZone.prototype._checkStable /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9415:25
NgZone/this._zoneImpl<.onLeave /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9387:21
NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onInvokeTask /@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9239:29
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask /zone.js/dist/zone.js:355:24
Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask /zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:29
ZoneTask/this.invoke /zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:29
```

Any ideas?

(cross-posted [on github](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1016))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(this is a reproduction of [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931922/angular-2-material-same-icon-from-same-file-displays-in-one-component-not-the/39054271#39054271) because the two issues are really the same)

I figured out that because `MdIconModule` itself has `MdIconRegistry` service in its `providers` array, every time another module imports it, a new instance of the service is provided. As a result, all components that are loaded at bootstrap time and that belong to the same `AppModule` share the same instance of this service.  However, components loaded later (via lazy-loading) have a *different* instance of the service and as a result cannot see the icons registered at bootstrap time.

With [help from James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010654/angular-2-how-to-make-singleton-service-available-to-lazy-loaded-modules), I've used the workaround of a specially crafted module that does not use `MdIconModule` at all, but rather declares the `MdIcon` class alone. I then provide the `MdIconRegistry` service separately, and only to the root `AppComponent`. The result is that there is only one instance of the service app-wide and icons registered at bootstrap time are available everywhere.

**Modified MdIconFixedModule**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, HttpModule],
    declarations: [MdIcon],
    exports: [MdIcon],
    providers: [],//leave empty to avoid multiple instances of MdIconRegistry
})
export class MdIconFixedModule {
    static forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule: MdIconFixedModule,
            //will be available only to whoever calls .forRoot()
            providers: [MdIconRegistry] 
        };
    }
}
```

Modules that need to just use icons can import `MdIconFixedModule` as this doesn't contain the `MdIconRegistry`. The `AppModule` that also needs to register icons imports `MdIconFixedModule.forRoot()` which does contain the service.

The details of this implementation [can be seen here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/qflUJ16v48gbIixfYJsY?p=preview)

This limitation of ng-Material Modules is slotted to be [fixed with the alpha 8 release](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1071).