# Angular 2 Material: same icon from same file displays in one component, not the other

Tags: svg, angular, angular2-material

I'm using `Angular 2 rc 5` with `ng2-Material alpha 7-2`.

The basic problem is that using `<md-icon svgIcon='icon'>` to show the same icon from the same svg file will work in one component but not the other even though `MdIconModule` and `MdIconRegistry` are provided to the root `AppModule`

**To replicate the problem**

- Open [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yNjE0hLNSPUSul859MKs?p=preview)
- Notice that `MdIconModule` and `MdIconRegistry` are imported as part of `MaterialModule.forRoot()` into the main `AppModule`
- Open the `AppComponent` and notice the call to `addSvgIconSet()` to register icons
- In the template, `<md-icon svgIcon='ic_account_box_24px'>` is used to display the icon. In the view the icon is shown successfully above the nav bar.
- Open `app/crisis-center/crisis.list.component` and open the Crisis Center in the view.
- Note in the template, the same `<md-icon>` is present. However, no icon is displayed above the crisis list in the view. The DOM inspector from browser dev tools shows that the angular parser didn't even recognize it as an angular component (in the dom, it's left exactly as in the code)

Because I imported the icon module and service into the root module I expected the service to be a singleton available to the whole app. Since I use that service to register the icons with `iconRegistry.addSvgIconSet()` in my bootstrapped `AppComponent`, I expected the icons to be accessible throughout the app.

PS: this may be related to what [I reported yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918170/angular-2-material-same-mdicon-that-works-in-one-component-fails-in-the-other), although in that case the app crashes; in this case the icon is just not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(this is a reproduction of [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918170/angular-2-material-same-mdicon-that-works-in-one-component-fails-in-the-other/39054312#39054312) because the two issues are really the same)

I figured out that because `MdIconModule` itself has `MdIconRegistry` service in its `providers` array, every time another module imports it, a new instance of the service is provided. As a result, all components that are loaded at bootstrap time and that belong to the same `AppModule` share the same instance of this service.  However, components loaded later (via lazy-loading) have a *different* instance of the service and as a result cannot see the icons registered at bootstrap time.

With [help from James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010654/angular-2-how-to-make-singleton-service-available-to-lazy-loaded-modules), I've used the workaround of a specially crafted module that does not use `MdIconModule` at all, but rather declares the `MdIcon` class alone. I then provide the `MdIconRegistry` service separately, and only to the root `AppComponent`. The result is that there is only one instance of the service app-wide and icons registered at bootstrap time are available everywhere.

**Modified MdIconFixedModule**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, HttpModule],
    declarations: [MdIcon],
    exports: [MdIcon],
    providers: [],//leave empty to avoid multiple instances of MdIconRegistry
})
export class MdIconFixedModule {
    static forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule: MdIconFixedModule,
            //will be available only to whoever calls .forRoot()
            providers: [MdIconRegistry] 
        };
    }
}
```

Modules that need to just use icons can import `MdIconFixedModule` as this doesn't contain the `MdIconRegistry`. The `AppModule` that also needs to register icons imports `MdIconFixedModule.forRoot()` which does contain the service.

The details of this implementation [can be seen here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/qflUJ16v48gbIixfYJsY?p=preview)

This limitation of ng-Material Modules is slotted to be [fixed with the alpha 8 release](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1071)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders  }       from '@angular/core';
import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular2-material/button';
import { MdCardModule } from '@angular2-material/card';
import { MdCheckboxModule } from '@angular2-material/checkbox';
import { MdCoreModule } from '@angular2-material/core';
import { MdInputModule } from '@angular2-material/input';
import { MdProgressCircleModule } from '@angular2-material/progress-circle';
import { MdToolbarModule } from '@angular2-material/toolbar';
import { MdMenuModule } from '@angular2-material/menu';
import { MdIconModule} from '@angular2-material/icon';

@NgModule({     
    exports:      [
      MdButtonModule,
      MdCardModule,
      MdCheckboxModule,
      MdCoreModule,
      MdInputModule,
      MdProgressCircleModule,
      MdToolbarModule,
      MdMenuModule,
      MdIconModule
    ]
})
export class MaterialModule {

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MaterialModule,
      providers: [
      ]
    };
  }

}
```

Comment: I've tried this setup. The problem is that when `MdIconModule` is exported, its service (`MdIconRegistry`) is included. So when I use this module in a component that is lazy-loaded, a different instance of the service gets injected in that component and as a result the icons that were registered with one instance of `MdIconRegistry` are not visible from the other component. Once I figured out what was going on, I was able to ask a better question and I worked it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010654/angular-2-how-to-make-singleton-service-available-to-lazy-loaded-modules